# Simple HTTPS POST in Android - Java

Tags: java, android, post, https

There are several code samples online and several perfectly good solutions in SO already, but none of them are clear enough for me to understand and *I don't want to just copy someone's code without understanding it*.

Doing a post to an *HTTP* page is pretty simple, 6 lines or so, but all the examples of *HTTPS* are much longer and harder to grasp.

Could someone provide a (**heavily commented**) short simple snippet or link to a good tutorial that explains how it's done without all the bells and whistles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below function to make https post request. If you don't get what the code exactly doing at which point, you can put it in comment below. I will help you if know the answer.

```
private static char[] HEX_CHARS = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
    '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
StringBuffer messagebuffer = new StringBuffer();

private String makeHTTPSPostRequest(String httpsURL) throws IOException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException,
        CertificateEncodingException {
    final HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(httpsURL)
            .openConnection();
    con.connect();
    final Certificate cert = con.getServerCertificates()[0];
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    md.update(cert.getEncoded());
    InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    int ch;
    long len = con.getContentLength();
    if (len != -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            if ((ch = dis.read()) != -1) {
                messagebuffer.append((char) ch);
            }
    } else {
        while ((ch = dis.read()) != -1)
            messagebuffer.append((char) ch);
    }

    dis.close();
    return dumpHex(md.digest());
}

private static String dumpHex(byte[] data) {
    final int n = data.length;
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n * 3 - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        sb.append(HEX_CHARS[(data[i] >> 4) & 0x0F]);
        sb.append(HEX_CHARS[data[i] & 0x0F]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This does not answer his question, he said there are plenty of these available. He wants the comments.

Comment: Code is as simple as everyone can understand. if there are any doubt than I will put the comment where he\she need it.

Comment: there is no explanation/comments whatsoever. Also poor indentation and unnecessary line breaks. I'm sorry but this is not what I'm looking for. Maybe if you could edit the code in your example but as is, I will not accept this answer. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: hell, i don't even understand the first line.. what is the significance of those chars?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

It's a very simple http post. also its asynchronous.

Comment: thank you @lalangfatz but that doesn't look like it supports https, correct?

Comment: it does @Adelphia. this is what I used with https requests.